# SVG background not filling canvas in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas whose height and width attributes are not mentioned during creation. I update the height and width of it through javascript so that it always fills the viewport height and width. When I use a jpg for the canvas background, it works fine. But when I use a svg, I find that it gets clipped to the default canvas dimension ( 300px x 150px ). But if I set the height and width of the canvas as attributes directly in the tag, then the svg fills the entire canvas properly. Why does SVG behave this way and how can I fix i?

Comment: why the question is tagged fabricjs?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, because I am using fabricjs? Sorry if that was not made apparent.

Comment: Please write a more explicative question, insert a working snippet where the behaviour can be observed. with the current question is hard to understand what are you doing.